# Is there any advantage of using hash datastructure when bucket size is less?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash, hashmap, hashtable

1) If the bucket size is very less in terms or 8,16,... 64 is there any advantage of using hash datastructure for search/insert/delete? The bucket size is less because of the embedded system environment.

---

2) If there are no advantages, what are the other alternatives for improving search/insert/delete performances?

---

3) If there are advantages, what is best implementation of hash when bucket size is fixed and range of the input keys are known?

Comment: Do you mean "number of buckets" when you say "bucket size"? Or the number of entries a bucket can hold?

Comment: Each bucket can hold only one entry(no seperate chaining) and bucket size is number of  such buckets

Comment: The number of buckets you want is mostly a function of the number of entries you need to store. With just 5 entries, 8 buckets is probably not bad.

Comment: If you have very few buckets, you will arrive at a trade-off point where just iterating over all elements is cheaper than computing the hash function. I would be very surprised if a hashmap is cheaper than a linear search on, say, 8 elements.